Strategy for Sending Data to Azure AI Search with High Frequency
I'm using Azure AI Search and need advice on handling data submission efficiently. My system has hundreds of GBs of data, and I could generate multiple entries per second—potentially dozens depending on traffic.
Here Are My Challenges:

Each individual data entry is small (e.g., user creation, messages).

Undecided on whether to send each entry immediately or batch them.

Concerned about sending too many requests to Azure AI Search simultaneously. Could this cause issues?


Main Questions:

Should I send each individual data entry immediately, or accumulate and send them every 10-20-30 seconds?

If I send entries individually, what frequency is considered too frequent and might lead to throttling or performance issues?

If I batch the data, what strategies work best for interim storage? Should I use a database, Redis, or something else?

What are the best practices for optimizing data submission intervals and ensuring efficient indexing?


Any insights or experiences with managing high-volume data submissions in Azure Cognitive Search would be greatly appreciated!

You can store it in blob storage or database and use it for indexing.

Regarding your suggestion to store data in blob storage or a database for Azure Cognitive Search indexing, could you clarify:
Does this mean I should store data in batches and then send it afterward?
Or is it simply a suggestion in case I want to store the data before sending, providing options for where I can do so? @JayashankarGS

Store all your data as it arrives at blob storage. When you rerun the indexer, it automatically takes new documents.

You store each individual data entry either in sql database or in azure blob storage as they arrives.
In blob it can Json , text, csv etc. here are the  supported format
Next, index it by following the steps mentioned in this document for blob storage as data source.
When new data arrives to blob storage, you just run the indexer in regular interval like daily or every hour.
It automatically adds new documents to index.

If you want to reindex entire documents then Reset and Run indexer.
Next, if you want to remove the document from index you enable deletion tracking in data source.

This removes the document from index when you rerun the indexer after deleting documents from blob storage.
By using above approach, you can index data from blob storage in a regular interval.

Thank you for the guidance. I need near real-time updates every 30 seconds, but I can trigger indexers at 5-minute intervals. I'm considering sending each data individually, at dozens per second, and I'm concerned about throttling with the Push API.
Do you know the specific throttling limits for data ingestion? The documentation says static limits for the Indexing API and dynamic limits for the Query API. What should I think regarding these throttling limits?
Throttling limits @JayashankarGS

You need to check for the indexer limits https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits.
Maximum  indexing load per invocation is 10,000 documents in Free tier. According to the tier you check it. If the documents are exceeding the limit then do the batch indexing for that particular limit.

I wanted to share the solution I found for improving performance when submitting documents to Azure AI Search.
The documentation wasn't very clear on this, but It was suggested that batching data before sending significantly improves performance. Using indexers wasn't suitable for my needs since they sync at a minimum of once every 5 minutes.
I conducted a test using a free-tier Azure AI Search instance. I sent 10, 50, 100, and eventually 200 concurrent POST calls. I even scaled up to sending 200 concurrent calls 100 times. Despite the free-tier limitations, the overall response time remained stable, and I didn't encounter any 503 errors.
In conclusion, even with the free tier, the service's compute power and throughput are robust enough to handle 500-1000 push requests effectively. I hope this helps anyone facing similar challenges!

whoah - you're using it that much, and not hitting limits with the free tier - 50MB, 3 indexes, etc? i guess if it's really simple data like you mentioned. not sure why you'd use ai search for that, but very interesting...
